# Is there an official complete table with all CSS properties and all possible values?

Tags: css, w3c

Is there an official complete table with all CSS properties and all possible values? I'm looking for all possibilities, including the latest "CSS4"/modules.

I'm looking for the all encompassing version of https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html (but that one only has CSS 2.1).

This lists out all properties, but doesn't include all possible values on the same page: https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/all-properties

Answer (score 0):

Full CSS catalog with information about possible values https://websitesetup.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/wsu-css-cheat-sheet.pdf

And this is also great: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/css-3-cheat-sheet-pdf/

-> PDF https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/d7fb67af-5180-463d-b58a-bfd4a220d5d0/css3-cheat-sheet.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [official W3 specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/tr-groups-all). These are (mostly) respected by all major browsers.

For a more simple and user friendly but incomplete list see [css-tricks almanac](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there's no such *official* list.

However the current work is conveniently located in a [single w3c/csswg-drafts repository](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/) (https://drafts.csswg.org/ and https://drafts.csswg.org/css-2018/ help make sense of the list) and the spec markup is designed to be [machine-readable](https://www.w3.org/Style/spec-mark-up.en.html#Property). So if you're looking for a fun way to spend a weekend and learn a bit about the CSS specifications, you can try to generate one yourself!

Alternatively, you could ask around to see if the person who maintains the script to generate https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/all-properties is willing to share it with you.